# can i uninstall multiple redundant Windows SDK to recover disk space?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sdk, visual-studio-2019, windows-10-universal

I'm running out of disk space on my system. Space is filling up consistently even when I'm not installing any software. Free space went from 100 GB free space to 70 GB in a few weeks.

When I checked in my installed Softwares these were shown to take up much space.

[image]

As you may notice the following are the versions:

1. `10.0.18362.1`
2. `10.0.17763.132`
3. `10.0.17134.12`
4. `10.0.16299.15`

I want to ask if I can uninstall these safely from my system?
If not all, then which ones may I?
Are these redundant copies?
Also I'm not sure if these are needed for Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code. Either ways I was deciding to remove VSCode & VS. So assuming that, will it be safe to uninstall these 4 SDK in image above?